# Hodge decomposition thm. Why $\Delta(E^p)=d\delta(E^p)\oplus\delta d(E^p)=d(E^{p-1})\oplus\delta(E^{p+1})?$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, harmonic-analysis, adjoint-operators, hodge-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{Img}{Im}$
In Warner's "Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups" we read that
$$E^p\stackrel{(1)}{=}\Delta(E^p)\oplus H^p\stackrel{(2)}{=}d\delta(E^p)\oplus\delta d(E^p)\oplus H^p\stackrel{(3)}{=}d(E^{p-1})\oplus\delta(E^{p+1})\oplus H^p,$$
Where $E^p$ are smooth $p-$forms on given compact oriented Riemannian manifold $M.$

He states that it is sufficient to prove the decompositon in $(1),$ for $(2)$ and $(3)$ follow from three facts:

$$\Delta=\delta d+d\delta\hspace{10pt}<d\alpha,\beta>=<\alpha,\delta\beta>\hspace{10pt}\Delta\alpha=0\iff d\alpha=0\wedge\delta\alpha=0$$

So I conclude, that he means
$$\Delta(E^p)=d\delta(E^p)\oplus\delta d(E^p)=d(E^{p-1})\oplus\delta(E^{p+1})\hspace{20pt}(*)$$
follows from above three facts. However I do not see how to prove it. I only have following inclusions based on the knowledge about non-degenerated bilinear forms:
$$\Img\Delta\subset(\ker\Delta)^\perp=(\ker d\delta\cap\ker\delta d)^\perp\supset(\ker d\delta)^\perp+(\ker\delta d)^\perp\supset(\Img d\delta)^\perp+(\Img\delta d)^\perp$$
I used above fact that $\Delta,d\delta$ and $\delta d$ are self adjoint.

> So I ask how to prove $(*)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $d\delta E^p,\ \delta dE^p$ are orthogonal :

$$ (d\delta x, \delta d y)=(dd
\delta x,dy) =0 $$

In further we have $ \Delta E^p = V_1\oplus V_2,\ V_1:=d\delta E^p,\ V_2:= \delta
 d E^p $

(2) Note that $V_1\subset W_1:=dE^{p-1},\ V_2\subset W_2:= \delta E^{p+1}\ \ast$ are orthogonal

(3) Hodge proved first equality So second is followed. We will use $E_p=V_1\oplus
 V_2\oplus H^p\ \ast\ast$ : If $dx\in W_1,\ y\in H^p$, then $$ (dx,y)=(x,\delta y)=0 $$

(Note that $H^p=\{ x| dx=\delta x=0 \}$) That is, $W_1\oplus
W_2\oplus H^p\subset E_p$ So from this and $\ast,\ \ast\ast$ we
complete the proof

Comment: (1),(2),(3) are done more straightforward that I imagined. In the last part we used that $(H^p)^\perp\subset\Delta(E^p).$ it is not evident from his proof, that this is required.

Comment: I add more explanation. I do not understand your comment

Comment: I still do not see how we get the inclusion $W_1\oplus W_2\oplus H^p\subset E_p$ without $(H^p)^\perp\subset\Delta(E^p).$ In (3) you take arbitrary $dx\in W_1$ and you show that for all $y\in H^p$ $(dx,y)=0.$ So it tells me only that $dx\in (H^p)^\perp.$

Comment: $W_1\oplus W_2\oplus H^p$ is set of $p$-forms so that inclusion is clear. And yes $W_1\oplus W_2 \subset (H^p)^\perp =V_1\oplus V_2\subset W_1\oplus W_2$

Comment: I thought that you introduce new symbol $E_p:=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus H^p,$ cause originally I put $E^p$ as p-forms. 

But still, as I see in your comment, you used that $(H^p)^\perp=V_1\oplus V_2$ which is not evident from decomposition $E^p=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus H^p...$ or maybe it is, but I do not know the reason why.

Comment: As I commented in answer (cf. (3)) Hodge already proved $E_p=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus H^p$ which implies $(H^p)^\perp=V_1\oplus V_2$ Yes I used this fact.

Comment: Yes, and this holds because $E^p=H^p\oplus(H^p)^\perp.$ And this holds cause $H^p$ is finite dimensional and we have a split short exact sequece (not unique cause we need to fix orthonormal basis of $H^p$) $$0\to H^p\to E^p\to (H^p)^\perp\to 0$$ with splitting given by projection on $H^p.$ Thx.